# Is there a formula to approximate $\pi$ in the form of $\dfrac{p}{q}$?

Tags: approximation, fractions, pi

Is there a formula which helps in approximation of $\pi$ as $\dfrac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I got this site though : [http://qin.laya.com/tech_projects_approxpi.html ] which shows the various fractions from $\pi \approx \frac{3}{2}$ to $\approx\frac{2646693125139304345}{842468587426513207}$

So is there any relation/formula/easy trick/anything which can help to find these fractions??

***Thanks!!***

Comment: One way would be to simply take truncations of Wallis product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product This will give a series of rational approximations which is getting closer and closer to $\pi$, but at very slow rate.

Comment: Maybe a useful reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80 for a listing of various methods of approximating $\pi$. It notes that the continued fraction representation can be used to generate successive best rational approximations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to approximate pi with rational numbers, and there is a whole industry devoted to doing this to huge degrees of accuracy. Perhaps the simplest rational approximations to pi are found in its [continued-fraction expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html). The first two are $3$ and $\frac{22}7$, and already the fourth, $\frac{355}{113}$, is accurate to six decimal places.

Comment: Continued fractions give the best rational approximations for a given denominator size.

Answer (score 4):

This series converges to $\pi$ from above, starting at $\frac{22}{7}$

$$\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{96 (160 k^2+422 k+405)}{(4 k+3) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17)}$$

A simpler one is
$$\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}$$

[A series to prove $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652812/a-series-to-prove-frac227-pi0)

Comment: It is interesting to compare above summation with integration per $$\pi = \frac{22}{7} - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: As a follow up to previous comment, in the summation case the denominator is 8-th degree polynomial and the numerator is 2-nd degree polynomial (both with regards to "k"), while in the integration case the denominator is 2-nd degree polynomial and the numerator is 8-th degree polynomial (both with regards to "x").

Comment: In fact, it was the other way: the series has eight factors in the denominator in an attempt to match Dalzell's integral symmetry. However, the numerator is not that symmetric, which is the reason for the linked question...

Comment: @Alex Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654104/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-pi

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There are several.  The best know is the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):

$$1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \dots = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

This is an infinite series but just do the first few terms to get:
$$\pi = 4\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7 - 5\cdot7 + 3\cdot7 - 3\cdot5}{3\cdot5\cdot17} = \frac{304}{105} \approx 2.8952380952380\ldots$$
Okay, I never said it would be a *good* approximation, but each successive term gets closer. Add $4/9$ to that and we get $3.3396825396825\ldots$

**EDIT**
Here's a better one:
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(4n+1)(4n + 3)}$$
So for the first three terms we get:
$$\pi = 8\left(\frac13 + 7\frac15 + 11\frac19 + 15\frac1{13}\right) \approx 3.017071817071817\ldots$$

Comment: The best known?! The convergence of the Leibniz series is (as you note) awful!

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I think he meant the "best-known" (though that is arguable in itself) and not "(the) best (formula) known". Ah, the travails of the English Language. :)

Comment: Also, the Leibniz formula should properly be called the Madhava-Leibniz formula, as the Indian mathematician Madhava is now known to have discovered it centuries before Leibniz.

Comment: I *definitely* meant the most known.  I never really paid attention to methods (as long as I know *someone* can calculate pi I don't really care about the details).  It's the one I see mentioned the most.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Not sure why I was so aggressive when I posted that comment!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to obtain rational approximants of $\pi$ is by using continued fractions.

But the *simple* continued fraction for $\pi$ has no pattern - you will never be able to guess it without knowing the value of $\pi$ first.

So, you can use one of the better, regular continued fractions for $\pi$, like this one:

$$\pi=3+\dfrac{1}{6+\dfrac{3^2}{6+\dfrac{5^2}{6+...}}}$$

It converges much better than simple series, for example:

$$\pi=3+\dfrac{1}{6+\dfrac{3^2}{6+\dfrac{5^2}{6}}}=\frac{1321}{420}=3.14524$$

The next fraction (with $7^2$) looks nicer:

$$\frac{989}{315}=3.13968$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#.CF.80) for another three regular fractions for $\pi$.

You can also use infinite products instead of series, because you will immediately get a fraction at every step. Like Wallis product for example:

$$\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3}\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5}\frac{6}{7}...$$

But it converges very slowly and gives huge fractions, for example:

$$\prod^{20}_{n=1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{151115727451828646838272}{48691767863540419643025}=3.10352$$

Answer (score 1):

There is one made by Ramanujan in 1914 that aproximates $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

$$\frac{4}{\pi}=\frac{1}{882}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(4n)!}{(4^n n!)^4}\frac{1123+21460 n}{882^{2n}}$$